# how to measure level shock using vibration sensor and arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, shields, gsm, gps

[image]

My project title is about crash detection, by using this kind of vibration sensor. When the sensor reads the shock (which is when I knock the sensor) more than 50, it assumes it's a crash and will send via SMS the location of the crash to me. The problem is, that I tried to connect the sensor with Arduino, but when I knocked the sensor, the value of the shock did not change. How can I fix this?

VCC I connected to 5V,
GND to Arduino GND,
A0 to analog input Arduino,
D0 is not used

This is my code

---

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#include <TinyGPS.h>



TinyGPS gps;
SoftwareSerial ss(2, 3);
SoftwareSerial GSMx(5, 11);

static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms);
static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec);
static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len);
static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps);
static void print_str(const char *str, int len);

//-------------------VARIABLE-------------------------------
float LastLon;
String dataString = "";
String DateString = "";
String TimeString = "";
int Sens1Pin = 0;
float Sens1;
int update=0;
float LastLat;
int dummy=0;
int RQScount;
int countERROR;
int countPHONE;
int countOK;
int commaPosition;
int index = 0;
int SMSx=0;
int ALARM=0;
int LOCK=0;
float latx;
float lonx;
int OUTRANGE=0;
String result[10];
String USER1 = "\"019*******\"";
String Data1 = "";
String Data2 = "";
String Data3 = "";
String Data4 = "";
String head = "";
String phone = "";
String pword = "";
String MESSAGE1="";
String MESSAGE2="";
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = true;  // whether the string is complete
boolean command = true;
boolean Enabled = false;
boolean Enabled1 = false;
boolean Enabled2 = false;
boolean Enabled3 = false;
boolean GPS_NoData = false;
float SHOCK;
int count;
float flat, flon;
  unsigned long age, date, time, chars = 0;
  float ExistingSpeed;
float SpeedGPS;


//----------------------------------------------------------

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  GSMx.begin(9600);
  inputString.reserve(150);
 delay(8000);

  //Serial.println("AT");
  GSMx.println("AT");
  delay(2000);
 // Serial.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  GSMx.println("AT+CMGF=1");
  delay(2000);
 // Serial.println("AT+CMGD=1");
  GSMx.println("AT+CMGD=1");
  delay(2000);
  //Serial.println("AT&W");
  GSMx.println("AT&W");
  delay(2000);

  //Serial.print("AT+CMGS=");
  delay(300);
  //Serial.println(USER1);
  GSMx.print("AT+CMGS=");
  delay(300);
  GSMx.println(USER1);
  delay(1000);
  //Serial.print("GPS-GSM TRACKER---ACTIVATED ");
  GSMx.print("Controller is now ready...");
  delay(200);
  //Serial.println(char(26));
  GSMx.println(char(26));
  delay(4000);

  //Serial.println("Sats HDOP Latitude  Longitude  Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum");
  //Serial.println("          (deg)     (deg)      Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail");
  //Serial.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

  ss.begin(9600);
  //--------------------------------------


  stringComplete = true;
}

void loop()
{

  Sens1 = analogRead(Sens1Pin);           //read the value from the sensor
  Sens1 = (5.0 * Sens1 * 100.0)/1024.0;  //convert the analog data to digital

  SHOCK = ((390 - Sens1)/390)*100;

  unsigned short sentences = 0, failed = 0;
  static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;


 if (SHOCK > 40){
    ALARM=1;
  }

  if (ALARM==1){
    delay(100);

    if (SMSx==0){
     //  Serial.print("AT+CMGS=");
                GSMx.print("AT+CMGS=");
               // Serial.println(USER1);
                GSMx.println(USER1);
                delay(1000);
               // Serial.print("ALARM ALERT!! at location, lat:");
                GSMx.print("EMERGENCY ALERT!!");
               // Serial.print(flat,5);
                GSMx.print(TimeString);
                GSMx.print(" ");
                GSMx.print(DateString);
                GSMx.print(" (LAT/LON/SPEED) ");
                GSMx.print(dataString);


                GSMx.print("www.google.co.in/maps/place/");
                GSMx.print(flat,5);
                GSMx.print(",");
                GSMx.println(flon,5);


                delay(200);
               // Serial.println(char(26));
                GSMx.println(char(26));
                delay(4000);

      SMSx=1;
      ALARM=0;
    }
  }



  print_int(gps.satellites(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_SATELLITES, 5);
  print_int(gps.hdop(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_HDOP, 5);
  gps.f_get_position(&flat, &flon, &age);
  print_float(flat, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 10, 6);
  print_float(flon, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 11, 6);
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  print_date(gps);
  print_float(gps.f_altitude(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ALTITUDE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_course(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_float(gps.f_speed_kmph(), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_SPEED, 6, 2);
  print_str(gps.f_course() == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(gps.f_course()), 6);
  print_int(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? 0xFFFFFFFF : (unsigned long)TinyGPS::distance_between(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON) / 1000, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  print_float(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE : TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON), TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE, 7, 2);
  print_str(flat == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_F_ANGLE ? "*** " : TinyGPS::cardinal(TinyGPS::course_to(flat, flon, LONDON_LAT, LONDON_LON)), 6);

  gps.stats(&chars, &sentences, &failed);
  print_int(chars, 0xFFFFFFFF, 6);
  print_int(sentences, 0xFFFFFFFF, 10);
  print_int(failed, 0xFFFFFFFF, 9);
  //Serial.println();

   if (flat < 0.1){
    GPS_NoData = true;
  }
  if (flat > 0.1){
    GPS_NoData = false;
  }



  if (flat != LastLat){
               if (GPS_NoData == false){
                 LastLat = flat;
               }
             }
             if (flon != LastLon){
               if (GPS_NoData == false){
                 LastLon = flon;
               }
             }


  //---------------------------------GSM FUNCTION-----------------------------------------

              Serial.print(TimeString);
              Serial.print(" ");
              Serial.print(DateString);
              Serial.print(" ");
              Serial.print(flon,5);
              Serial.print(", ALARM:");
              Serial.print(ALARM);
              Serial.print(", DATA:");
              Serial.print(dataString);
              Serial.print(", SHOCK LEVEL: ");
              Serial.println(SHOCK);

if (stringComplete == true){

  //Serial.println("AT+CMGR=1");
   GSMx.println("AT+CMGR=1");

  count = 0;
  countERROR = 0;
  countPHONE = 0;
  countOK = 0;
  stringComplete = false;
  Enabled = false;
  Enabled1 = false;
  Enabled2 = false;
  Enabled3 = false;
}

  while (stringComplete == false){
 // count = count + 1;
       while (Serial.available() > 0){

        char inChar = Serial.read(); 
        inputString += inChar;


        if (Enabled2){
          Data2 += inChar;
          countPHONE = countPHONE + 1;
            if (countPHONE == 10){
            Enabled2 = false;
            }
        }


        if (inChar == 'E'){
          Enabled1 = true;
         }
         if (Enabled1){
          Data1 += inChar;
          countERROR = countERROR + 1;
                if (countERROR == 5){
                 Enabled1 = false;
                      if (Data1 == "ERROR"){
                        stringComplete = true;
                      }
                      if (Data1 != "ERROR"){
                        countERROR = 0;
                        Data1 += "";
                        Enabled1 = false;
                      }
                }

        }

        if (inChar == 'O'){
          Enabled3 = true;
         }
         if (Enabled3){
          Data4 += inChar;
          countOK = countOK + 1;
               if (countOK == 2){
                if (Data4 == "OK"){
                  stringComplete = true;
                }
                if (Data4 != "OK"){
                  countOK = 0;
                  Data4 = "";
                  Enabled3 = false;
                }
               } 
         }
        if (inChar == '+'){
          if (count > 5){
            Enabled2 = true;
          }
        }
        if (count > 80){
            stringComplete = true;

         }



       }
}


       if (stringComplete){
         /*

                */
            // Serial.println(inputString);
            index = 0; 
    do
  {
      commaPosition = inputString.indexOf('*');
      if(commaPosition != -1)
      {
          result[index++] = (inputString.substring(0,commaPosition));
          inputString = inputString.substring(commaPosition+1, inputString.length());
      }
    //  else
    //  {  // here after the last comma is found
    //     if(inputString.length() > 0)
    //       Serial.println(inputString);  // SMS message after final splitting
                             // print it
     // }
   }
   while(commaPosition >=0);
     MESSAGE1 = result[2];
     MESSAGE2 = result[3];





         if (result[1] == "LOCATION") {
    //            Serial.print("AT+CMGS=");
                GSMx.print("AT+CMGS=");
    //            Serial.println(USER1);
                GSMx.println(USER1);
                delay(1000);
    //            Serial.print("DEVICE TRACKING, lat:");
                GSMx.print("DEVICE TRACKING, lat:");
    //            Serial.print(flat,5);
                GSMx.print(flat,5);
    //            Serial.print(", lon:");
                GSMx.print(", lon:");
    //            Serial.println(flon,5);
                GSMx.println(flon,5);
    //            Serial.print("www.google.co.in/maps/place/");
    //            Serial.print(flat,5);
    //            Serial.print(",");
    //            Serial.println(flon,5);
                GSMx.println(" SPEED:");
                GSMx.println(SpeedGPS);
                GSMx.print("www.google.co.in/maps/place/");
                GSMx.print(flat,5);
                GSMx.print(",");
                GSMx.println(flon,5);


                delay(200);
    //            Serial.println(char(26));
                GSMx.println(char(26));
                delay(4000);
    //            Serial.println("AT+CMGD=1");
                GSMx.println("AT+CMGD=1");

                delay(4000);

            }


                              if (result[1] == "RST") {
    //            Serial.print("AT+CMGS=");
                GSMx.print("AT+CMGS=");
    //            Serial.println(USER1);
                GSMx.println(USER1);
                delay(1000);
    //            Serial.print("Alarm reset...");
                GSMx.print("Alarm reset..");
                delay(200);
    //            Serial.println(char(26));
                GSMx.println(char(26));
                delay(4000);
    //            Serial.println("AT+CMGD=1");
                GSMx.println("AT+CMGD=1");
                ALARM=0;  SMSx=0;

                delay(4000);

            }





       inputString = "";
       result[1] = "";
       result[2] = "";
       result[3] = "";
       result[4] = "";
       result[5] = "";
       result[6] = "";
       Data1 = "";
       Data2 = "";
       Data3 = "";
       Data4 = "";
      // Serial.flush();

      // stringComplete = true;
  delay(100);
  Sens1 = analogRead(Sens1Pin);           //read the value from the sensor
  Sens1 = (5.0 * Sens1 * 100.0)/1024.0;  //convert the analog data to digital
  SHOCK = ((390 - Sens1)/390)*100;
  if (SHOCK > 50){
    ALARM=1;
  }
  Serial.print("SHOCK LEVEL: ");
  Serial.println(SHOCK);
  delay(100);
  Sens1 = analogRead(Sens1Pin);           //read the value from the sensor
  Sens1 = (5.0 * Sens1 * 100.0)/1024.0;  //convert the analog data to digital
  SHOCK = ((390 - Sens1)/390)*100;
  if (SHOCK > 40){
    ALARM=1;
  }
  Serial.print("SHOCK LEVEL: ");
  Serial.println(SHOCK);
  delay(100);
  Sens1 = analogRead(Sens1Pin);           //read the value from the sensor
  Sens1 = (5.0 * Sens1 * 100.0)/1024.0;  //convert the analog data to digital
  SHOCK = ((390 - Sens1)/390)*100;
  if (SHOCK > 40){
    ALARM=1;
  }
  Serial.print("SHOCK LEVEL: ");
  Serial.println(SHOCK);
  delay(100);
  Sens1 = analogRead(Sens1Pin);           //read the value from the sensor
  Sens1 = (5.0 * Sens1 * 100.0)/1024.0;  //convert the analog data to digital
  SHOCK = ((390 - Sens1)/390)*100;
  if (SHOCK > 40){
    ALARM=1;
  }
  Serial.print("SHOCK LEVEL: ");
  Serial.println(SHOCK);
       }


  delay(100);
 // smartdelay(300);
}
//--------------------------------------START OF SUBROUTINES-------------------------------------
static void smartdelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void print_float(float val, float invalid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (val == invalid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
    //  Serial.print('*');
    //Serial.print(' ');
    dummy=0;
  }
  else
  {
   // Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
     // Serial.print(' ');
     dummy=0;
  }
  smartdelay(0);
}

static void print_int(unsigned long val, unsigned long invalid, int len)
{
  char sz[32];
  if (val == invalid)
    strcpy(sz, "*******");
  else
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
 // Serial.print(sz);
  smartdelay(0);
}

static void print_date(TinyGPS &gps)
{
  int year;
  byte month, day, hour, minute, second, hundredths;
  float Speed;
  unsigned long age;
  gps.crack_datetime(&year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second, &hundredths, &age);
  if (age == TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE)
   // Serial.print("********** ******** ");
   dummy = 1;  

  else
  {

    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d ",
        month, day, year, hour, minute, second);
   // Serial.print(sz);



  //  hour = hour+8;
  //  sprintf(lcd_buffer,"%02d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d",day,month,year,hour,minute );


    hour = hour + 8;
    if (hour > 23){
      hour = hour - 24;
    }
    dataString="";
    TimeString="";
    DateString="";
    ExistingSpeed = gps.f_speed_kmph();
    Speed = gps.f_speed_kmph();
    SpeedGPS = Speed;



   TimeString = String(hour) + ":" + String(minute) + ":" + String(second);
   DateString = String(day) + "/" + String(month) + "/" + String(year);
   dataString = String(flat,5) + "  " + String(flon,5) + "  " + String(Speed,2);







  }
  print_int(age, TinyGPS::GPS_INVALID_AGE, 5);
  smartdelay(0);






    }


static void print_str(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
  //  Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartdelay(0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a minimal sketch that just reads the vibration sensor and prints what it reads?

Comment: no, i didn't try it yet, i want the sensor that i used compatible with the coding as this is my fourth sensor that i had try on.

Comment: So step one is to confirm that the sensor is working and that it gives you the kind of values you expect - with a minimal program that reads the sensor and prints out the values.

Answer (score 1):

From the huge amount of code it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong, but I noticed that you used `0` for the analog pin which is not the same as `A0`.

Your pin number should be defined as:

```
int Sens1Pin = A0;
```

Comment: On the UNO the two are interchangeable, since the analog pins are completely separate from the digital pins. It sees the numbers 0 to 5 or 14 to 19 (the latter are what A0-A6 alias to) with an analogRead() and maps then to the 6 available analog channels.

Comment: oh, i'm little bit confuse,  what do you means by maps then to the 6 available analog channels? could you give me an example according to my coding.

Comment: @Majenko I see. I just checked the pin definition and not the implementation of `analogRead`.

Comment: yes, my sensor implemented for analogRead, that why i use int Sens1Pin=0; but the problem is, my sensor cannot read the shock level, so the device cannot detect the shock level when it crash. because i use if else selection which is if shock level > 40, is assume as crash and sending me a SMS. There is no error at my coding i give above. just i not sure why i can't read the level of sensor when i knock it. i had try to change int SenslPin= A0; but the result are same. can u help me.

Comment: @MissBlur Did you try just reading the sensor and sending it to serial, to see if it works? Maybe try to use the digital pin on the module, since you just need a trigger at a threshold value. And adjust the sensitivity with the pot.

Comment: @gre_gor i had tried to testing the sensor and sending it to the serial, and i found out that my sensor do not detect the vibration because the result are not change. so the problem is my sensor right ? but when i run the code, the light(LED) of my sensor are just fine. do i need to replace the sensor? or i just need to try another code??